# Why am I getting errors which cannot logically happen?

Tags: postgresql, errors, null

I'm ready for the nuthouse at this point. This error makes me want to stab my eyes out after staring at the screen and testing stuff for literally MONTHS now!

The offending code, which looks to me like it cannot possibly fail:

```
dbcall('INSERT INTO dblog_query_strings (query_string) VALUES ($1) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING', $query_string);
dbcall('INSERT INTO dblog_file_paths (file_path) VALUES ($1) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING', $file_path);
dbcall('INSERT INTO db_log (query_string_id, file_path_id, seconds) VALUES
(
    (SELECT id FROM dblog_query_strings WHERE query_string = $1),
    (SELECT id FROM dblog_file_paths WHERE file_path = $2),
$3)', [ $query_string, $file_path, $seconds ]);
```

The error is:

```
pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR:  null value in column "query_string_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 2020-08-27 00:37:32.419107+02, null, null, 0.00065708160400391).
```

I've made **very** sure that the actual string variables sent to PG are indeed populated, so *they* aren't `null` for sure. And this query *mostly* works, but every now and then spits out this nonsensical error. That's very important to point out here. It's working most of the time, but sometimes messes up for some reason.

I cannot for the life of me figure out WHY that happens. I very clearly INSERT the strings to the first two tables before I then run the third and final INSERT query, which grabs the ids from the tables.

I cannot see any way in which these queries could fail. It looks impossible. Whether the values exist already or not is irrelevant, because I INSERT with "ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING" in the end. And then I only grab the ids after that has run. These queries are not asynchronous or anything, which otherwise could explain this in that the third INSERT is run before one of the two first or something.

Why do the SELECTs inside the third INSERT sometimes receive `null` instead of the existing-for-sure values from the tables? I don't understand it and this kind of thing, where I look at the code and simply cannot see any error, drives me absolutely insane for real.

Please offer some kind of hint.

I've removed the BEGIN/COMMIT I used around this query before, because I kept getting "deadlock detected" errors all the time. I thought I would stop getting errors after removing those, but instead I get these null errors... Even though they cannot happen according to the code.

So how can they still happen? What have I fundamentally misunderstood about databases/PostgreSQL?

Comment: **Note:** Several unkind or rude comments have been edited or deleted here in response to multiple community flags. A reminder to all: We have relatively high expectations for behaviour on this site, with enforcement as necessary. Please help out by confining comments [to their most constructive uses](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and by treating our [Code of Conduct](https://dba.stackexchange.com/conduct) as a *minimum standard*.

Answer (score 1):

The clue is that you said that you got a lot of deadlocks when you ran the three statements in a single transaction.

That shows that there are lots of concurrent data modifications that affect the same rows.

Consequently, you are probably falling prey to a race condition: there is nothing that keeps a concurrent transaction from deleting a row between the execution of the first statement and the execution of the third one.

The solution would be pessimistic locking to prevent that.

Unfortunately you cannot use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` for that, you will need logic like this:

```
LOOP
    var1 := NULL;
    SELECT id INTO var1 FROM dblog_query_strings WHERE query_string = $1 FOR UPDATE;
    IF var1 IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO dblog_query_strings (query_string) VALUES ($1) RETURNING id INTO var1;
    END IF;
    EXIT WHEN var1 IS NOT NULL;
END LOOP;

LOOP
    var2 := NULL;
    SELECT id INTO var2 FROM dblog_file_paths WHERE file_path = $1 FOR UPDATE;
    IF var2 IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO dblog_file_paths (file_path) VALUES ($1) RETURNING id INTO var2;
    END IF;
    EXIT WHEN var2 IS NOT NULL;
END LOOP;

INSERT INTO db_log (query_string_id, file_path_id, seconds) VALUES (var1, var2, $3);
```

That whole code will have to run in a single transaction. If you encounter a deadlock, you have to repeat the transaction.

Comment: You are welcome to try and find a better way. A deadlock will be detected automatically, and the code will throw an error. You catch the error, roll back and try again.